# How can I mock a DynamoDB scan operation using aws-sdk-mock?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-mock

I`ve beed following the aws-sdk-mock documentation to mock a DynamoDB service so I can test my functions, which works fine like this:

```
const AWSMock = require("aws-sdk-mock");
    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    const mockedData = require("./mockData");
    export async function getDynamoItem() {
    AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS);
    AWSMock.mock("DynamoDB.DocumentClient", "get", (params, callback) => {
       console.log("DynamoDB.DocumentClient", "get", "mock called");
       callback(null, mockedData);
    });
  const input = { TableName: "", Key: {} };
  const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
  });

  const response = await client.get(input).promise();
  AWSMock.restore("DynamoDB.DocumentClient");

  return response;
}
```

But I have a function that scans a DynamoDB table like this:

```
export async function readAll(table) {
  const params = {
    TableName: table,
  };

  const scanResults = { Items: [] };
  let items;

  do {
    items = await cli.scan(params).promise();
    items.Items.forEach((item) => scanResults.Items.push(item));
    params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
  } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== "undefined");

  return scanResults;
}
```

When I try to use the same logic into the mock, I keep getting a region error, which means that my mock is trying to read my table directly, which it is not supposed to do.

Does anyone know how can I "mock" a scan operation using aws-sdk-mock?

I've been checking every piece of  documentation I can find, but couldn't find something helpful for  this problem.